# Spark cluster with Jupyter Notebook tmp directory settings

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem (rather a requirement) that all temporary files are written to a specific directory.

I currently set:

```
spark.local.dir /path/to/my/other/tmp/directory
spark.eventLog.dir /path/to/foo/bar
```

This kinda works, but I still get some files in the default `/tmp` folder.
Some `<some hash>_resources`, a folder called `hive`, a lot of `liblz4-java<some hash>.so` and `snappy-<version>-<hash>-libsnappyjava.so` files.

I would like to set the path for these temporary files, any ideas? And what would be the best practice for something like this?

Comment: Did you check the hive-site.xml for its temp file locations?